# Maximum number of calls allowed in ethereum

Tags: solidity

What is the maximum number of plausible calls one can do to a contract? Per second?

"Calls", requests for information. Not transactions, but requests for information.

Answer (score 0):

In theory there is no limit.

In reality, you will be restricted by the following:

1. Gas costs
2. Block gas limit. This is currently 15M. The most simple transaction costs 21000 gas, so you can fit about 715 of such transactions in a block
3. Block interval. This is currently around 15 seconds. So a new block is mined every 15 seconds.

So, assuming you pay enough (in gas price) to get all of your transactions included in the next block, you can theoretically do 715 transactions in 15 seconds, or **48 transactions per second**.